# PHP line break between content and date

Tags: php

I am trying to have the title and date break to two lines but they are currently running in one line.

PHP novice here needs help!

```
<span class="kb-topic__list-article-title"><?php echo esc_html(get_the_title()); echo nl2br(the_date());?> </span></a>
```

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your original question to add any new information.

Comment: not a PHP issue, but an HTML one

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is echo a line break and not use the `nl2br()` function:

```
<span class="kb-topic__list-article-title">
    <?php 
        echo esc_html(get_the_title()); 
        echo '<br>';
        echo (the_date());
     ?>
</span>
```

Comment: I tried that and adding the br actually breaks my site and shows a syntax error.

Comment: quote typo @jay

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're jumping in and out of PHP and HTML, I would separate the dynamic content from the HTML layout.  You can accomplish your goal in this fashion with something like the following:

```
<span class="kb-topic__list-article-title">
    <div>
        <?php echo esc_html(get_the_title()); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php echo (the_date()); ?>
    </div>
</span>
```

You can then style the HTML elements however you need to in order to achieve the exact layout you're going for.  However the above code will get you the basic effect of putting the output of your two functions on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can also:

```
<span class="kb-topic__list-article-title">
<?php echo esc_html(get_the_title());?>
<br>
<?php echo (the_date());?>
</span>
```

have the brake not in php